# Cant't show spark dataframe after scoring data - incompatible input types for column x

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks, mlflow

I have created an xgboost model in databricks. I am trying to score the model on production data. The same dataprep code is used before training the model and and for scoring.

```
import mlflow
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct

model_uri = f"models:/{model_name}/1"

predict = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri, result_type="double")

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(table)
output_df = spark_df.withColumn("prediction", predict(struct(*spark_df.columns)))
```

The code runs without giving me any errors, but if I try

```
output_df.show(20)
```

I get an error:

mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Incompatible input types for column x. Can not safely convert int64 to int32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I  had the order of operations in the dataprep mixed up, so that I converted floats to int and replaced missing numerical values before doing a one hot encoding of a categorical varaible. That last variable did not get the proper treatment since it was created after cleaning up the rest of the data

Answer (score 0):

This says that the model expects an int, but was passed a long. For the offending column, what type is it in `spark_df`? what type is expected according to the model signature logged with the model? You can cast the column to int if you are sure that's safe before applying the model.